# Contact Form 7 Margin Styling Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, margin, contact-form-7

I'm building a site for a small company ([please take a look here](http://www.mediacreature.co/services/)) and I'm having an incredibly difficult time figuring out why I can't get the text boxes on the contact form (upper right corner) to line up correctly.

No matter what I do to the CSS, the margins are never even on the left and right side of the form fields. That's all I want is for the margins to be even on both sides.

This is a contact form 7 plugin on wordpress. All the inputs on the form are at 90% width currently. When I increase it to 100% width, I'd expect them to have the same width as their parent element (which is the form that they are contained in) but they don't. They are always longer than their parent element at 100% width. Can some one please give me a little insight as to how to fix this problem? Has anyone had this or a similar problem and knows how to fix it?

I'd post code, but I'm really not even sure which code to post. I have been inspecting the elements with firebug all day but I can't find the source of the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am growing rather short tempered with this contact form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
 #sidebar #custom_cf7-3 .heading, #sidebar #custom_cf7-3 .wpcf7{

     margin-left:20px;
 }
```

Comment: I just tried the code you gave me. It didn't seem to change anything. I've tried messing around with the margins for these form fields but for some reason it doesn't seem to have an effect on it.

Comment: I've been trying it between FF and Chrome.

Comment: Weird I tried the same and it worked...hold on let me check again

Comment: Another thing I'm curious about - If you change the widths of the text fields to 100% in your screen, do they extend out beyond the edge of the form?

Comment: @DigitalBrent You overrule the margin  with `.wpcf7 {margin: 0px !important;}` Remove this part.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the margin: 0px !important. However the margins are still not quite even. They are damn close. That's for sure, but I need to know why I can't get these things exactly even. Why do the input fields become wider than their parent element at 100% width? I know I'm being a perfectionist here but now it's beyond the look of the site. I just need to know what the heck is making it so that these margins are not even. Thanks so much for your help though guys. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Nevermind... Figured it out. There was one pixel of padding on both the text fields and the textarea. This was what was causing that extra bit of overlap and the margins to not be exactly even. Sorry guys. As a designer that was just really pissing me off that they wouldn't align correctly. Thanks for your help. Couldn't have done it without you!